# Azure Storage SDK method PushFileChangesAsync fails to create hash

Tags: xamarin, azure-blob-storage

I am playing with the file sync feature of Azure Storage Blob but I am having an issue and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I am following this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-blob-storage .

Everything seems to work fine except when calling the sync function and the SDK method PushFileChangesAsync(), here is throwing an exception:

`System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented.
at System.Security.Cryptography.IncrementalHash.CreateHash (System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithmName hashAlgorithm) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/8b53676d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Core/System.Security.Cryptography/IncrementalHash.cs:39 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.MD5Wrapper..ctor () [0x00022] in :0 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.StreamExtensions+d__11[T].MoveNext () [0x00112] in <f4e6ba1ca4d14d46a8bbc1b278ad5087>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/8b53676d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/8b53676d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/8b53676d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/8b53676d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/8b53676d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:113 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob+<>c__DisplayClass27_0+<<UploadFromStreamAsyncHelper>b__0>d.MoveNext () [0x001a8] in <f4e6ba1ca4d14d46a8bbc1b278ad5087>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/8b53676d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/8b53676d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/8b53676d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/8b53676d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/8b53676d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:113 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Files.StorageProviders.AzureBlobStorageProvider+<UploadFileAsync>d__2.MoveNext () [0x00107] in <dd371d553c0d487e80dfa0907713ae77>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/8b53676d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/8b53676d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/8b53676d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/8b53676d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/8b53676d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:113 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Files.MobileServiceFilesClient+<UploadFileAsync>d__4.MoveNext () [0x00122] in <dd371d553c0d487e80dfa0907713ae77>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/8b53676d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/8b53676d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/8b53676d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/8b53676d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/8b53676d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:113 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Files.Operations.CreateMobileServiceFileOperation+<ExecuteOperation>d__3.MoveNext () [0x00182] in <dd371d553c0d487e80dfa0907713ae77>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/8b53676d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/8b53676d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/8b53676d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/8b53676d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/8b53676d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:113 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Files.Operations.MobileServiceFileOperation+<Execute>d__13.MoveNext () [0x0007b] in <dd371d553c0d487e80dfa0907713ae77>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/8b53676d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/8b53676d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/8b53676d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/8b53676d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/8b53676d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:113 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Files.MobileServiceFileSyncContext+<PushChangesAsync>d__13.MoveNext () [0x00189] in <dd371d553c0d487e80dfa0907713ae77>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/8b53676d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/8b53676d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/8b53676d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/8b53676d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3969/8b53676d/source/xamarin-macios/_ios-build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:113 
  at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Files.MobileServiceSyncTableExtensions+<PushFileChangesAsync>d__71[T].MoveNext () [0x0006f] in :0`

Looks like CreateHash method in System.Security.Cryptography.IncrementalHash is not implemented and I am not sure I should be in charge of doing that. I have tried to google this but It seems I am the only one having this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Hey, I am facing the same exact issue. Did you manage to solve this problem? Any blob upload method fails with the above exception.

Comment: I have filed an issue here https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-files-client/issues/89 but no answers so far. For now I am changing my logic  following this tutorial https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/web-services/storage/azure-storage/

Comment: I have managed to sort it out. There is an issue already being worked on. Something about some hashing algorithm that Xamarin has not implemented yet which the azure client SDK v8.0.0 uses. All you have to do is use the version before that which is 7.2.1. I wasted 20 hours on this BS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue and posted it on msdn forums. I think on that thread you can find all the information you need.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c8941ca0-36b1-4381-9876-fc583ca43942/uploadfromstream-not-working-missing-implementation-in-library?forum=windowsazuredata

Comment: It's good that you're providing answers and I don't want to discourage you. it's worth noting however links can become unreachable. [How to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) _Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline._